# How can I simply extract a variable with Rascal Regex

Tags: rascal

If I process a simple string with a regex, I expect I can extract variables. The examples in the manual states that the extraction results in a stored variable. This does not work as expected. If I do the following regex:

`/\w*<subtext:text>\w*/ := "myfulltextstring"`

I would expect the variable `subtext` to contain the string `text`. But it is undeclared. If I declare `subtext` before executing, it is empty. What is the simple way to do this extraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of the variable `subtext` is not global, but "to the right of the match":

```
/\w*<subtext:text>\w*/ := "myfulltextstring" && bprintln(subtext)
```

or

```
if (/\w*<subtext:text>\w*/ := "myfulltextstring") {
  println(subtext);
}
```

or

```
str x = "";
if (/\w*<subtext:text>\w*/ := "myfulltextstring") {
  x = subtext;
}
```

Just having a declaration for `subtext` in an outer scope is not enough, since it would be masked by the regex variable.